# storm streamparse spout "Complete latency" always at 0

Tags: python, apache-storm, streamparse

I use streamparse for a while now but i'm stuck on one subject.
We use `storm-0.10.0` and `streamparse==2.1.4`.  We let all the default value (`no auto_anchor = False` or something like that ) .

We have no ack or fail method implemented in spout and we don't call any ack or fail method in bolts .

On bolt side, process latency and execute latency looks correct . Process latency are >> execute latency.

My concern is about the `spout Complete Latency` that we can find in the storm UI . It's always at 0.00 . I read that complete Latency is the total time spent of a message in the topology .
So it's a very good KPI to follow as it can help to detect a lake of workers, tasks or even nodes.

In one bolt , i did a self.log(tup) and i do have a tuple.id with this kind of output  :

> name:engine-bolt Tuple(id=u'2213630928741732943',
>   component=u'request-spout-1',
>   stream=u'default',
>   task=24,
>   values= etc
>   ...

So how can i do to get some values about the "Complete Latency" for spouts ?

If you need anything else , please ask :)